# Removing the border from an owner-drawn listbox

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, listbox, ownerdrawn

I've made an owner-drawn listbox by deriving CListBox, but I don't want it to have a border. Instead the border will be painted in the background of the parent dialog, so my listbox will look like it has a custom border. How can I remove the border? Is there a flag or a function to override in my derived class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `WS_BORDER` window style.